# Emails are not getting received by the user while using celery with Django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, amazon-ses

I am using Django1.8.2, celery3.1.23 and RabbitMq as the broker. I am using Amazon ses for email. Now when I'm sending email from django shell it is getting received by the users but when I schedule it through celery it's getting received.

here is project files:

**project/src/settings/base.py** *(censored)*

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 3

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
SERVER_EMAIL = 'abc@example.com'
ADMINS = [
        ('abc', 'abc@example.com')
]
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'abc@example.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 10
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abcjdjdlasskjjdklsaj'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'djkashdklahsjdhasljkdhjksahdjkashdjakhdak'
```

**project/src/settings/celery_app.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from kombu import serialization
serialization.registry._decoders.pop("application/x-python-serialize")

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.production')
app = Celery('project')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**project/src/app/tasks.py**

```
@task()
def send_mail_reminder(reminder_id):
    logger.info("Send Email")

    try:
        reminder = Reminder.objects.get(pk=reminder_id)
    except Reminder.DoesNotExist:
        return
    body = "{0}".format(reminder.message)
    try:
        send_mail("Reminder App Notification",body,settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,[reminder.email])
        logger.info("Email Successfully send")
        return "Email Successfully send"
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("There is some problem while sending email")
        print e
        return e
```

**project/src/app/models.py**

```
def schedule_reminder(self):
        """
        Schedule a celery task to send the reminder
        """
        date_time = datetime.combine(self.date,self.time)
        reminder_time = arrow.get(date_time).replace(tzinfo=self.time_zone.zone)

        from .tasks import send_sms_reminder, send_mail_reminder
        # result=''
        # result = send_sms_reminder.apply_async((self.pk,),eta=reminder_time,serializer = 'json')
        # else:
        result = send_mail_reminder.apply_async((self.pk,),eta=reminder_time, serializer = 'json')
        return result.id

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Now we need to do is ensure Django calls our 
    schedule_reminder method every time an Reminder object is created or updated.
    """
    # Check if we have scheduled a celery task for this reminder before
    if self.task_id:
        #Revoke that remnder if its time has changed 
        celery_app.control.revoke(self.task_id)

    # save our reminder, which populates self.pk,
    # which is used in schedule_reminder

    # Schedule a reminder task for this reminder
    self.task_id = self.schedule_reminder()

    # Save our reminder again with the task_id
    print "Args:%s,Kwargs:%s"%(args,kwargs)
    print self.task_id
    super(Reminder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the celery log
**celery.log**

```
[tasks]
  . RemindMeLater.settings.celery_app.debug_task
  . Reminder.tasks.send_email_reminder
  . Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder
  . Reminder.tasks.send_sms_reminder

[2016-08-04 23:21:15,507: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2016-08-04 23:21:15,520: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-08-04 23:21:16,532: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-08-04 23:21:16,546: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Rohans-MacBook-Pro.local ready.
[2016-08-04 23:22:21,260: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[e45b972a-d937-4ed9-bd75-bab331b6ed47] eta:[2016-08-04 23:22:00+05:30]
[2016-08-04 23:22:21,582: INFO/Worker-2] Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[e45b972a-d937-4ed9-bd75-bab331b6ed47]: Send Email
[2016-08-04 23:22:21,608: INFO/MainProcess] Task Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[e45b972a-d937-4ed9-bd75-bab331b6ed47] succeeded in 0.0274002929982s: None
[2016-08-04 23:22:46,629: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[7b14ef7b-c123-42c8-90d8-2baf4122963a] eta:[2016-08-04 23:24:00+05:30]
[2016-08-04 23:24:00,895: INFO/Worker-3] Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[7b14ef7b-c123-42c8-90d8-2baf4122963a]: Send Email
[2016-08-04 23:24:00,920: INFO/MainProcess] Task Reminder.tasks.send_mail_reminder[7b14ef7b-c123-42c8-90d8-2baf4122963a] succeeded in 0.0263162209994s: None
```

When I sending email from the Django shell without using celery that time it's going. And when I doing like this that time also it's going

**mail_test.py**

```
from datetime import datetime,time
from Reminder.models import Reminder
import arrow

t = time(23,35)
date = datetime.today().date()
a = Reminder.objects.create(message="Hello world",date=date,time=t,email="abc@gmail.com",completed=False)
from Reminder.tasks import send_mail_reminder

# b = send_mail_reminder(a.id)
# print "b:",b

date_time = datetime.combine(a.date,a.time)
reminder_time = arrow.get(date_time).replace(tzinfo=a.time_zone.zone)
c = send_mail_reminder.apply_async((a.id,),eta=reminder_time, serializer='json')
print "c:",c
```

and then executing below command on the terminal, adds a task in the celery and gets executed successfully.

> ./manage.py shell < mail_test.py

When I am using post_save signal then also it's working as expected.

Comment: this looks wrong ```os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.production')``` - shouldn't it just be 'settings.production'?

Comment: also does settings.production import from settings.base - cause thats where your email settings are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. I used post_save signal to call the task and save with the task_id.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Reminder)
def send_email_signal(sender,instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return
    self = instance
    date_time = datetime.combine(self.date,self.time)
    reminder_time = arrow.get(date_time).replace(tzinfo=self.time_zone.zone)

    from .tasks import send_sms_reminder, send_mail_reminder
    result = send_mail_reminder.apply_async((self.id,),eta=reminder_time, serializer = 'json')

    if result.id:
        instance.task_id = result.id
        instance.save()
```